# How do you make javaFx apps with modules?

Tags: javafx

It seems like java 9 has been around for a long time, but a search in **Google** and **Github** did not bring results, although it seems like the **idea is simple**:

One module (**Core**) in which the window is initialized, and **one or more modules** that add (for example) Tabs to this window. Clicking on a tab leads to the Module Controller.

Can someone show a simple example in **openSource**, or **their public repository**?

**UPDATE**

building a javafx application with modules is not a problem. I don't understand how to make them look like plugins (each module adds functionality and has its own view), and if there is no module, the application does not crash, it just loses functionality.

I don’t know if it’s possible to leave a link to github here (if not, I’ll remove it). see simple example [link](https://github.com/deni5n/javafxwplugins.git). in the console, the modular assembly works fine, but I don’t know how to reach the controllers and fxml in the plugin module (((

Comment: Did you check here? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ Their examples us modules, so you could structure your modules as you like. Here is a link to the [modular versions](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Modular)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with javafx. At first reading, you can use a service provider.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://github.com/trashgod/modular) or [this](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-fxdemos)? Going forward, please focus on a specific design goal that your current approach precludes.

Comment: If you want a plugin-like architecture, then should probably make use of the `java.util.ServiceLoader` API. That will involve declaring appropriate `provides` and `uses` directives in your module descriptors. The basic idea is that you'd need to define a Service Provider Interface that provides the necessary API for your plugin-aware module to get the needed data, perform the needed actions, and so on. Then your plugin-provider modules would implement the SPI as appropriate.